# How to connect client/server in C (Beej's Guide to Network Programming)

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am working through a simple tutorial for C network programming found here:
https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/index.html

After reading through it, my plan was to implement a testing client/server program, and then start to play around, modify things, add stuff, etc.  I implemented the program found here (the first client/server set dealing with TCP connections):
https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html

Basically, a "server" runs on one machine, and when the client connects, the server just sends "Hello, world!"  This works fine when I run both on the same machine and connect to localhost.

However, I am unable to connect between different machines (tried on both a Debian and OpenBSD server, no iptables/pf rulesets).  The connection just times out, and I'm not really sure why.  I can ping and ssh into both.

Can anyone, specifically anyone familiar with this tutorial, point me in the right direction?

Edit: no X on servers, so no screenshots, but netstat -tlnp | grep 3490 gives me nothing.

netstat -an shows tcp connection listening on 3490.

Comment: Show us `netstat -tlnp | grep 3940`.

Comment: after you learn this , move to a professional api ,ampq or mpi etc..etc...

Comment: Could you pls post some code snippet & also the errno value after tcp connect fails?

Comment: Jay - errno 60.  H2CO3 -- very cool stuff! Thanks for that, I will definitely check it out.  I feel like I should learn all this sockets stuff just for...completeness, I guess, but I will a definitely give your library a shot.

Comment: Beej's guide is an abomination. Pick up a copy of Stevens.

Comment: tbert - just looking into that now, actually.  I'm realizing that if I've gotten this far but don't know how to figure out a simple error, I probably need something more in depth.

Comment: @tbert I used to say that a lot - got flamed and downvoted for it too. I'm just really glad someone else feels the same :-)

Comment: @cnicutar it is just insane the number of mission-critical projects (e.g., nagios and derivatives) which just cut-and-paste code from someone who obviously doesn't understand sockets, or apparently Unix programming in general. Seriously, alarm(3) as a way to handle read timeouts?

Comment: Here's a simple working client/server app that follows Beej's guide closely. You may find it useful as an example: https://github.com/countvajhula/dummyclientserver

Comment: Try `lsof | grep LISTEN` or the Network Utility app instead.  `netstat` on Mac is different.  Also, the port might get translated to "colubris," so `grep 3490` may not work.  See [IANA port registry for 3490](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=3490)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your servinfo being filled any where in the code

// Server should allow connections from any ip address

```
  serv_info.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Also you might need to fill family and port

// Fill server's address family

```
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

To need more details, here is a working server i wrote on a forum
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/63924-a-simple-tcp-server-using-linux-c-api/

Answer (score 1):

Right before `if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {` print out the value of `p->ai_addr` I'd bet it's 127.0.0.1. This would cause communication to work fine on one computer, but not happen anywhere else.

To listen on all interfaces, bind on 0.0.0.0.